# How to filter an alias by a set of IDs?

Tags: apache-pig

I have a huge alias `HUGE` which has a field `ID`.
I also have an alias `COUNTS`, indexed by `ID`.
I want to create an alias `FILTERED` which is identical to `HUGE` but only containing the `ID`s with small counts, i.e., something like:

```
A = join HUGE by ID, COUNTS by ID;
B = filter A by COUNTS::N < 1000;
FILTERED = foreach B generate HIGE::*;
```

The problem is that `HUGE` is, well, huge (1B rows), and the number of `ID`s I am removing is relatively small.
So, instead of the hugely expensive `join`, I want to be able to do something like:

```
C = foreach (filter COUNTS by N >= 1000) generate ID;
FILTERED = filter HUGE by ID not in C;
```

here C is relatively small (say, a 10k rows).

How do I do this?

Comment: If your question is answered but the answer raises another one for you, it's best to ask a new question instead of editing the original.

Comment: @WinnieNicklaus: you are right, sorry. please take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24812457/how-to-project-an-alias-using-a-wildcard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `C` (rows of `COUNTS` with `N >= 1000`) is quite small, you can use a [replicated join](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.12.0/perf.html#replicated-joins) so that it is performed in memory with no reduce phase. This will add minimal processing to whatever else you are doing with `HUGE`.

*Note that in your example you filtered by `N >= 1000` but you stated you wanted `ID`s with *small* counts. Not sure which of those is what you intended.

Comment: 1. I want those _NOT_ in `C`. 2. Joining with `C` has to be outer and it is incompatible with replicated.

Comment: You can still use a replicated join with a left join.