# How to project an alias using a wildcard?

Tags: apache-pig

Once I do a `join A by id, B by id`, I get an alias with fields `A::f...`, `B::f..`.
Is there a way to project it on only the `A` fields?

```
C = join A by id, B by id;
D = filter C by B::n < 1000;
E = foreach D generate A::*;
```

I get

```
Unexpected character '*'
```

What I want is `E` with the schema *identical* to `A` (i.e., `describe E` and `describe A` should print the exact same things).

How do I do that?

Comment: Do you mind if the new schema still has `A::` prefixed to all the fields?

Comment: I would rather not. The alias is later saved as Json and read by others...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [project-range expression](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.12.0/basic.html#prexp) to get part of the way there.

Unfortunately, there is no way to systematically strip the `A::` prefix. If you know the name of the last field of `A` (suppose it's `last`), you can do this:

```
E = foreach D generate .. A::last;
```

If you wanted just the fields from `B` you would do

```
E = foreach D generate B::first ..;
```

If you really need to apply a specific schema, perhaps you could just define a macro that applies this schema whenever you need it, so you can overwrite any of the changes that come from grouping, joining, etc.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to have a common alias name after joining. but you can generate specific columns from the join results.
For Example,

```
A = load 'data1' as (id,name,addr);
B = load 'data2' as (id,name2,addr2); 
C = join A by id,B by id;        //Now C has id,name,addr,id,name2,addr2

D = Foreach C generate($0,$1,$2);
```

Now the relation D has the 'A' relation columns such as id,name,addr only.